# Muffled speakers - software issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, sound-volume, speakers

MacBook Pro 2016 15.4". Lately my speakers go from perfectly clear to a very muffled sound almost all the time. Selecting a different frequency in the Audio/MIDI configuration or killing `coreaudiod` solves this issue for a second or two, after which the sound goes back to muffled. I've tried the usual reboot, resetting SMC and PRAM. As the speakers CAN sound normal (even though only for a very short time) I assume this is a software issue. Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Having the exact same issue, MacBook Pro 2017. Found a long thread about a similar issue but it only happened when increasing the volume, where as my issue (and by the sound of it, yours too) has nothing to do with the volume.

Comment: A bit late, but I would like to add that this is the case for me as well. When I increase the volume above a certain level, say ~50%, it almost always gets muffled immediately.